# Kentico file permissions for image editor

Tags: kentico

I've given IIS_User modify access and confirmed this on the media disk folder, but i'm still getting a 'Insufficient file system permissions to edit this image.'

Could there be a permission level conflict between IIS_USER and the service level account Kentico is using through the app pool?

Answer (score 1):

Mark, if I understood you correct you are not using IIS_USER as Kentico app pool account. If this it correct - you do not have to grant any permission for it, but only for account configured for Kentico app pool instead.

Answer (score 0):

It can depend on how you set up the site, but what i would do is in IIS hit the "Basic Settings" on the right and see what your app pool is.

If it's a named one, try to right click on the website -> Permissions, and add the user "IIS APPPOOL\TheNameOfTheAppPool" and give full permissions there.

If that user doesn't show up, then try giving the IIS_IUSER full permission, test if it works, if it does then you can start scaling back permissions till it 'breaks' and stops working.  If it does't work, then you need to try the other users.